# Validate a student number with .match

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to disable the href when student number does not match, however student number does not appear to be defined.
The loginbtn is the id for the button that activates the href.

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function(e){
  var studentNumber = ("C10814698");
  studentNumber = studentNumber + $("#studentN").value;
  var studentNumberMatcher = /[A-Z][0-9]{8}/;
  var isValid = studentNumber.match(studentNumberMatcher);

  if ("studentNumber" !== isValid || ("studentNumber") === "") {
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert("Please enter a valid student number");
  }      
});
```

Comment: jQuery uses the `val()` method to get the value of an input. Try `$("#studentN").val()`

Comment: Also, you append the value together to form `studentNumber` which will make the value longer than 8 characters, yet the Regex says the value can *only* be 8 characters. Also `isValid` will hold an array, so testing it against a string will never work, and `"studentNumber" == ""` will also never be true as the strings don't match at all. I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I tried the value(), it disables the e.preventDefault

Comment: sorry im a student il try explain,

Comment: Please read the comments `value() !== val()`

Comment: I wanted to assign C10814698 to the studentNumber, check to see if the user input matches that studentNumber, if not disable the href to prevent login, if true allow login to take place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several syntax issues in your code, like using a non-existant `value` property instead of the `val()` method, comparing arrays to strings and confusing strings for variable names.

> I wanted to assign C10814698 to the studentNumber, check to see if the user input matches that studentNumber, if not disable the href to prevent login, if true allow login to take place

In which case you can amend your logic like this:

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function(e){
  var studentNumber = "C10814698";
  var input = $("#studentN").val();

  if (!input.trim() || studentNumber != input) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert("Please enter a valid student number");
  }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The match() method return an Array containing part matched in the string and null if there's no match. So in your case, the test will be :

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function(e){
  //var studentNumber = ("C123456789");
  var studentNumber = $("#studentN").val();
  var studentNumberMatcher=/[A-Z][0-9]{8}/;
  var isValid = studentNumber.match(studentNumberMatcher);

  if ($("studentNumber").val() === "" || isValid === null) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert("Please enter a valid student number");
  } else {
    alert("It's ok !");
  }
});
```

I also correct issues in your code ! :)

An example : https://jsfiddle.net/sdzpwrbx/1/